# Hierarchical menu of all Terms of a Vocabulary & Contents of the Terms

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, routes

I have `Category` *vocabulary* under which there are several *terms*, i.e `Tabs, Smartphones, Cellphones, Umbrellas`. There may me one or more *contents* of custom type under each of these *terms* **(A content could be linked with one term only)**. I want to generate a menu (automatically, if possible) like this:

[image: Screenshot of the hierarchical menu]

Now I've installed `Taxonomy Menu` module which allows to generate menu with one level hierarchy only (with only *terms* of a *vocabulary*, but no *contents* of the terms).

Is there a pretty solution of my problem? Thanks for caring :)

Comment: What do you mean by contents of the terms?

Comment: @shoaib-nawaz I have some custom Content-types named `products` - just like articles. Each content have exactly one `term` assined with it. 

By "contents of a the terms" I meant all contents havin that with a particular term.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just a straightforward menu - nothing automatic needed. When you add a new node, just choose it's parent menu item.

Comment: Hmm That's a solution I guess. But what it the creator does not has permission to add menu items?

I think generating it dynamically would be a better solution. Thanks for the answer by the way :)

Comment: You can limit which menu a node can be added to. It's built in to D7.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a module I found that comes with its own caveat: "...if incorrectly configured it could create thousands of menu items."

http://drupal.org/project/views_build_menu

Answer (score 0):

What kind of menu block are you using to display the menu?  You may need something like the nice menus module to display the hierarchy.  I have generated taxonomy menus of three levels using Taxonomy Menu.

Comment: The problem is not about generating Taxonomy Menu. What I want is listing associated contents under each of these taxonomy `terms`